Daily schedule - 'concatenating' multi-time periods into one block
I am working (in SQL Server 2016) on dental schedules, and by using LEAD (over PARTITION ...
I can produce data of this format:



Chair
Date
StartTime
EndTime
Blocked
Booked
Session




Cent 1
2025-03-03
490
500
1
0



Cent 1
2025-03-03
500
510
1
0



Cent 1
2025-03-03
510
520
0
0
Follow-up


Cent 1
2025-03-03
520
530
0
0
Follow-up


Cent 1
2025-03-03
530
540
0
0
Follow-up


Cent 1
2025-03-03
540
550
0
0
Follow-up


Cent 1
2025-03-03
550
560
0
1



Cent 1
2025-03-03
560
570
0
1



Cent 1
2025-03-03
570
580
0
1



Cent 1
2025-03-03
580
590
0
1



Cent 1
2025-03-03
590
600
0
0
Follow-up


Cent 1
2025-03-03
600
610
0
0
Assessment


Cent 1
2025-03-03
610
620
0
0
Assessment


Cent 1
2025-03-03
620
630
0
0
Assessment



What I need to achieve (and haven't been able to find elsewhere in this forum) is for the data to be grouped together to produce:



Chair
Date
StartTime
EndTime
Label




Cent 1
2025-03-03
490
510
Block


Cent 1
2025-03-03
510
550
Follow-up


Cent 1
2025-03-03
550
590
Booked


Cent 1
2025-03-03
590
600
Follow-up


Cent 1
2025-03-03
600
630
Assessment



ie, if the values of the last 3 columns don't change from the row before, they are added into a contiguous block. This example is for the situation where Follow-up was a single session from 510 to 600, but was afterwards overlayed by an appointment being booked.
The time values are minutes-after-midnight; they will be changed at the display stage.
I don't have experience with CTE, and trying to adapt the answers to other questions to my code isn't working - what I've found is for multi-day blocks being concatenated.
Any assistance much appreciated.
I have achieved the first table above, but can't find a reference to get to the 2nd.

It looks like just a group-by with min+max? Oh an you'll need a gaps-and-islands window function to split the groups out before you group-by. It you create a DBFiddle I'd have a go. Not going to type all your data in though.

Should work with CTE, LAG() & ROW_NUMBER(). Tested on SQL 2017.
;With
    alfa
    as
    (
        -- Assign new Session value depend of Blocked & Booked status
        SELECT Chair, Date, StartTime, EndTime,
        CASE 
            WHEN Blocked = 1 THEN 'Block'
            WHEN Booked = 1  THEN 'Booked'
            WHEN [Session] is null Then ''
            ELSE [Session]
        END as Session
        FROM _test
    ),
    bravo
    as
    (
        -- Compare this with the previous row and assign isNew flag
        SELECT *,
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG(Session,1) OVER(ORDER BY Chair,DATE,StartTime) = Session THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END isNew
        FROM alfa
    ),
    charlie
    as
    (
        -- Get the very Last changing slot and assign it's StartTime as PreviousStartTime one for the current slot
        SELECT *,
            CASE 
                WHEN isNew = 1 THEN StartTime
                ELSE (
                        SELECT TOP 1
                            StartTime
                        FROM bravo x
                        WHERE x.Chair = b.Chair AND x.[Date] = b.[Date] AND x.[Session] = b.[Session]
                            AND x.isNew = 1 AND x.StartTime < b.StartTime
                        ORDER BY Chair,[Date],StartTime desc
                    ) END as PreviousStartTime
        FROM bravo b
    ),
    delta
    as
    (
        -- Get Partitioned by PreviousStartTime Ordered on the EndTime descending for each slot to filter on last step
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Chair,Date,PreviousStartTime ORDER BY Chair,DATE, EndTime desc) rn
        FROM charlie
    )
    
SELECT Chair, [Date], PreviousStartTime as StartTime, EndTime, [Session]
    FROM delta
WHERE rn = 1 -- important desc order in previous step to ensure every slot group have one rn = 1
ORDER BY Chair,[Date],StartTime

Note: In order to debug your CTE try partial results one by one...
Step1:
With alfa as ( SELECT... FROM myTable) Select * from alfa

Step 2:
With alfa as (Select...), bravo as (Select... FROM alfa) Select * FROM bravo

etc....

I really appreciate your time in helping me.
